# I can't run TRUNK CHECK (trunk.io)

Tags: github, next.js, trunk-check

[My terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWOFO.png)
I'm following a video on Youtube that he code a clone Notion app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OaDyjB9Ib8&t=1549s) But i can't install TrunkCheck.

I tried to install with npm on TrunkCheck docs but it weren't working. Please help me.
Sorry my English so bad. Have a nice day!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.